# Cannot set new attribute on User model (using Devise & Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've added a new attribute/column (`locale`) to my User model (Devise). I will use this to save the User's chosen language to show the app in. This is selected by the user on the default Devise sign up form.

I have added the `devise_parameter_sanitizer` method to my application controller to permit the new parameter but everytime I add a new user, the `locale` column is always blank in the database.

If I follow the logs, I can see that the parameter is passed through to the create action, but for some reason it's lost somewhere in the middle.

Would love some guidance on what I'm doing wrong here.

**Log when creating a new user**

```
    Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-19 12:09:25 +0100
    Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"O3FEXmGBOnipEOLXkxNpRCKmpYVa5gc8oM2wauJbNt1iechdMQslDYZRSOgNEWeqsVFxcOQnxR2tbM2zNfAayw==", "user"=>{"email"=>"testytesty@testytesty1.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "locale"=>"sv", "commit"=>"Sign up"}
    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
    ↳ /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
    User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT ?  [["email", "testytesty@testytesty1.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
    ↳ /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
    User Create (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["email", "testytesty@testytesty1.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$EYTMfLLydcUvPjBjKcKxFe67OsTvwJao/SvP8PFrkctC95SkDQJDq"], ["created_at", "2019-01-19 11:09:25.326356"], ["updated_at", "2019-01-19 11:09:25.326356"]]
```

**Schema**

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "email", default: "", null: false
  t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
  t.string "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string "locale"
  t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
 end
```

**Application controller**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception, unless: -> { request.format.json? }
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :belongs_to_user
    before_action :set_locale

    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
        # Set a default current company scope for a use after signing in
        session[:current_company] = current_user.companies.first.id unless current_user.companies.empty?
        puts session[:current_company]
        companies_path
    end

    def set_locale
        I18n.locale = current_user.try(:locale) || I18n.default_locale
    end

    def belongs_to_user
        unless params[:controller] == 'devise/sessions' || params[:access_token].present? # TODO this is a potential security gap - patch this up so that it can't just any old token, it must be a valid one (look in the captables controller)
        @current_user_companies = current_user.companies unless !user_signed_in?

        if !params[:company_id].present?
            @company = Company.find(params[:id]) unless !params[:id].present?
        else
            @company = Company.find(params[:company_id]) unless !params[:company_id].present?
        end

        unless !@company
            if !@current_user_companies.include?(Company.find(@company.id))
            redirect_to companies_path, alert: "Access denied: You do not belong to this company"
            end
        end
        end
    end

    protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
        # Permit some additional params on the user sign up that aren't the default email, password etc
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:locale])
    end

end
```

**My sign up form**

```
    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %><br />
        <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <% if @minimum_password_length %>
        <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
        <% end %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :locale %><br />
        <%= select_tag(:locale, options_for_select([["English", "en"], ["Swedish", "sv"]])) %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

**Update: Full stack trace**

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-19 12:37:40 +0100
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"pAL2lKhnw4VEFx+umYkGDp+d87hrCRZ/xR0JaYof5X4J8Y4Acj8SOzB85mm6heRtNMXHpIPaI9l8+oDCeuLH5A==", "user"=>{"email"=>"jameselliotpember@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "locale"=>"sv", "commit"=>"Sign up"}
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
↳ /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT ?  [["email", "jameselliotpember@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
User Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["email", "jameselliotpember@gmail.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$N5A/.cfWXnAa/3upKDYlwOxLCt4zc8WPe2Jce.A60A3.SFR4jgoxe"], ["created_at", "2019-01-19 11:37:40.625528"], ["updated_at", "2019-01-19 11:37:40.625528"]]
↳ /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
(1.8ms)  commit transaction
↳ /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
↳ /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
LoginActivity Create (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "login_activities" ("scope", "strategy", "identity", "success", "user_type", "user_id", "context", "ip", "user_agent", "referrer", "created_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["scope", "user"], ["strategy", "database_authenticatable"], ["identity", "jameselliotpember@gmail.com"], ["success", 1], ["user_type", "User"], ["user_id", 1], ["context", "devise/registrations#create"], ["ip", "127.0.0.1"], ["user_agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"], ["referrer", "http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up"], ["created_at", "2019-01-19 11:37:40.630791"]]
↳ /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
(1.0ms)  commit transaction
↳ /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
[ActiveJob] Enqueued AuthTrail::GeocodeJob (Job ID: 3c096920-93b2-45aa-ba0d-3c9ff5a1466f) to Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007f9698b7c510 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://calmcap/LoginActivity/2>>
LoginActivity Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "login_activities".* FROM "login_activities" WHERE "login_activities"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
[ActiveJob] [AuthTrail::GeocodeJob] [3c096920-93b2-45aa-ba0d-3c9ff5a1466f] Performing AuthTrail::GeocodeJob (Job ID: 3c096920-93b2-45aa-ba0d-3c9ff5a1466f) from Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007f9698b4bbe0 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://calmcap/LoginActivity/2>>
[ActiveJob] [AuthTrail::GeocodeJob] [3c096920-93b2-45aa-ba0d-3c9ff5a1466f]    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
[ActiveJob] [AuthTrail::GeocodeJob] [3c096920-93b2-45aa-ba0d-3c9ff5a1466f]   ↳ /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
[ActiveJob] [AuthTrail::GeocodeJob] [3c096920-93b2-45aa-ba0d-3c9ff5a1466f]    (0.0ms)  commit transaction
[ActiveJob] [AuthTrail::GeocodeJob] [3c096920-93b2-45aa-ba0d-3c9ff5a1466f]   ↳ /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
[ActiveJob] [AuthTrail::GeocodeJob] [3c096920-93b2-45aa-ba0d-3c9ff5a1466f] Performed AuthTrail::GeocodeJob (Job ID: 3c096920-93b2-45aa-ba0d-3c9ff5a1466f) from Async(default) in 2.8ms
Company Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."user_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:10

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/companies
Completed 302 Found in 175ms (ActiveRecord: 4.5ms)
```

Comment: please truncate your database then try !

Comment: Ran `rake db:reset` but same problem sadly.

Comment: post your full stack trace

Comment: Added to main post

Comment: what is your rails version?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Try This!**

**change**

```
 <%= select_tag(:locale, options_for_select([["English", "en"], ["Swedish", "sv"]])) %>
```

**TO**

```
 <%= f.select :locale, options_for_select([["English","en"],["Swedish","sv"]]), {include_blank: "locale"} %>
```

Comment: Worked! Can you briefly explain it so I understand what the key change was?

Comment: @JP89: when you using form_for you should uesd looping variable example `f.select`

Answer (score 2):

If you check your logs you will see that your `locale` param does not come inside `user` scope. I've reformatted this line:

```
    Parameters: {
      "utf8"=>"✓",
      "authenticity_token"=>"...", 
      "user"=>{
         "email"=>"testytesty@testytesty1.com", 
         "password"=>"[FILTERED]", 
         "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"
      }, 
      "locale"=>"sv", 
      "commit"=>"Sign up"
}
```

So, you should add it inside `user` group of params.

As I understand this had happened because you didn't bind it to the form. You should use `f.select` instead of `select_tag` in your form.

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense combined with the answer below! Wish I could mark both as correct!